# GeoGraphics unable to download data for a given ranges from the Wolfram geo server

Tags: geography, geographics

Lately I'm having problems evaluating `GeoGraphics` functions in Mathematica (version 11.3).  For example, when I attempt to evaluate:

```
GeoGraphics[
  GeoPath[
    Flatten @ 
      {GeoPosition[{0, 0}], 
       Table[GeoDisplacement[{5 10^6, RandomReal[{0, 360}]}], {100}]}, 
    VertexColors -> Table[Hue[i/100], {i, 0, 100}]], GeoRange -> "World"]
```

I get a message:

> GeoGraphics::wdata: Unable to download data for ranges {{-90.,90.}, {-180.,180.}} and zoom level 1 from the Wolfram geo server."

GeoGraphics is not working as it used to.  How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Your code works with `$Version`

`(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)`

Comment: Thank you Bob! I rebooted my computer and suddenly GeoGraphics started working appropriately.  Go figure !?  Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi I think sometimes their servers just have issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears oo be just an intermittent server problem rather than a code issue.